# programmatically add an image to drupal node

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I have an url of an image that I wish to add, and a node object.

How do I programmatically add an image to a node in dripal 6?

Comment: What have you tried? Are you aware of [Drupal Answers](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: @Paul It's not that at Drupal Answers we are more permissive about the questions users ask. `:)`

Answer (score 1):

```
function image_style_add_form($form, &$form_state) {                                       
  $form['name'] = array(                                           
    '#type' => 'textfield',                    
    '#size' => '64',                               
    '#title' => t('Style name'),                                
    '#default_value' => '',                                                
    '#description' => t('The name is used in URLs for generated images. Use only lowercase alphanumeric characters, underscores (_), and hyphens (-).'),                      
    '#element_validate' => array('image_style_name_validate'),                       
    '#required' => TRUE,                                                         
  );                                                                  

  $form['submit'] = array(                         
    '#type' => 'submit',                         
    '#value' => t('Create new style'),                      
  );                                        

  return $form;                               
}

/**                       
 * Submit handler for adding a new image style.                     
 */                                
function image_style_add_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {              
  $style = array('name' => $form_state['values']['name']);              
  $style = image_style_save($style);           
  drupal_set_message(t('Style %name was created.', array('%name' => $style['name'])));  
  $form_state['redirect'] = 'admin/config/media/image-styles/edit/' . $style['name'];
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, you did not understand me. I mean it was a programmatic way, without loading the file.